# Calling method from within Form1 OR Calling buttons and text fields from another class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, call

Alright so:

I have in Form1 a `restart()` method that restarts my game, it also changes the labels, textfields, groupboxes etc to visible again.

I need this method to be in `Game.cs`, problem is, C# gives me loads of errors when I put this method in `Game.cs`

So I was wondering how I can either
 - Call a Form1 method from within Game.cs
 - Make the txts, lbls, and etc change work withing Game.cs

Thank you so much.

EDIT : Here's the restart method

```
public void restart() {
    lblBeschrijving.Visible = true;
    gbNaam.Visible = true;
    lblNaam.Visible = true;
    txtNaam.Visible = true;
    gbMuren.Visible = true;
    cmbMuren.Visible = true;
    lvlMuren.Visible = true;
    gbMoeilijkheid.Visible = true;
    cmbMoeilijkheid.Visible = true;
    lblMoeilijkheid.Visible = true;
    picBeginscherm.Visible = true;
    btnSpelen.Visible = true;
    tmrSnake_Tick.Enabled = false;
    nFoodTeller = 0;
    foodExtra.nEnabled = true;


    nScore = System.Convert.ToInt32(snakeScoreLabel.Text);

    snake = new Snake();

    DialogResult error;
    error = MessageBox.Show("Oh no! You killed the snake!\nDo you wish to play Again?\n\nYou scored " + nScore, "Snake Game Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    // ..and the snake's dead!

    if (error == DialogResult.No) {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I could split this functionality in two methods one that restarts gui which would be in form1 and other which restarts game logic and you would place it in Game.cs. So you can call them both in your Form1.cs

Comment: That would be pretty damn awesome.

I'll update the first post with my restart method entirely.

Comment: Sounds like Game.cs should have a custom event such as "Restart" and Form1 attaches to that event and resets the UI. keeps the UI separate from the game

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming I'm on the same level as you on programming games on c#. So here's my experience:

Game logic and UI are 2 separate entities, and UI controls the game not the other way around. This making sure that if the UI changes the game works anyway. Way to achieve this is to declare events and delegates that your main UI can hook into. So when you fire an event the UI receives the info. For example I used events to update the Score of Tetris:

https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/xand-tetris/trunk/

good luck exploring